# Eclim command not found

Tags: java, macos, vim, eclim

I already tried looking for my question but I didn't find anything on it. It went ahead and installed eclim so I could do Java development in Vim on Mac. Everything seems to work for the most part. I ran :PingEclim and :EclimValidate and there are no problems. All of the autocomplete seems to work. My only question is that I see on the eclim website them using an eclim or eclimd command. However, I tried running this in the terminal and it can't find this command. Am I missing something for the installation or is this for something else? When I want to use eclim, am I supposed to write out /Application/Eclipse.app/.../eclimd every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the the OS is Unix based,

locate eclimd

should find it, or even better

locate -b '\eclimd'

Once you have the path, create a symbolic link in you PATH

for example,

cd ~/bin

ln -sf /some/long/path/to/eclimd

If ~/bin is in your PATH environment variable then you can run eclimd from anywhere.